# FusionCharts/Widgets default export filename

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I try to set the default filename (clientside export):

```
 var myExportComponent = new FusionChartsExportObject("fcExporter1", "' lv_expurl_swf '");
     myExportComponent.exportAttributes.exportFileName = "test";
     myExportComponent.Render("fcexpDiv");
```

But the file download still shows the name FusionChart.jpg.

Any one an idea what's wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code: `myExportComponent.componentAttributes.defaultExportFileName = "test";`